# the ubuntu 16.04 software center doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, software-center

when I open the Ubuntu software centre it intermediately closes

What can I do??

Answer (score 0):

If you are in live Ubuntu (from usb), it is probably better to just install programs from the Terminal with `sudo apt-get install <package>`

If you have installed Ubuntu, try opening the software center from the Terminal by typing :

`software-center`

It will then give you data on what went wrong.

Also, you can re-install the software center with this command :

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install software-center software-properties-common software-properties-gtk`